# handlebars Error: The partial default/header could not be found

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Hi please i need help handlebars not rendering my partials instead its giving me the errors below.

Error: The partial default/head could not be found
at Object.invokePartial (C:\node-projects\cms blog\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:332:11)
at Object.invokePartialWrapper [as invokePartial] (C:\node-projects\cms blog\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:84:39)
at Object.eval [as main] (eval at createFunctionContext (C:\node-projects\cms blog\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\javascript-compiler.js:262:23), :8:31)
at main (C:\node-projects\cms blog\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:208:32)
at ret (C:\node-projects\cms blog\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:212:12)
at ret (C:\node-projects\cms blog\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\compiler.js:519:21)
at ExpressHandlebars._renderTemplate (C:\node-projects\cms blog\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handlebars.js:265:9)
at ExpressHandlebars. (C:\node-projects\cms blog\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handlebars.js:182:15)

app.js file below

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');


/*Use express*/
const app = express();

/* configure mongoose to connect to mongo DB*/
const {mongoDbUrl, PORT} = require('./config/configuration');

//Remove mongoose warning
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(mongoDbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
    .then(() => console.log('mongodb connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));


/* configure express app */
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , "public")));


/* Set up view engine to use handlebars*/

app.engine(
    "handlebars",
    hbs({
        extname: "hbs",
        defaultLayout: false,
    })
);




app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

/* Routes */

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('layout/default');
})



app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server connected on ${PORT} `);
});
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtFfA.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bro you named header.handlebars change it to head.hbs

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
 
var app = express();
 
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars